# A math function similar to "LatticeReduce" for finding linear independent basis

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, lattices

We would like to ask a math function similar to "LatticeReduce" for
finding linear independent basis.
The input is a list of vectors $M=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots\}$, with the following property:

There is a subset $O=\{w_1,w_2,w_3,\dots\}\subset M$,
such that $O$ is a basis, 
i.e. linearly independent and span $M$,
$$ v_i=\sum_a c_{ia} w_a.$$
Moreover, the coefficients $c_{ia}$ are **non-negative integers**.

An explicit example is the following:

$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 2 & 2 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}
\right),\quad
O=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$
where $O$ is the first 5 rows of $M$ and
$$M[[6]]=O[[1]]+O[[4]],\, M[[7]]=O[[1]]+O[[3]],\,\dots$$

In Mathematica form, the example is

```
m = {{1,  1,  1,  1,  1},
     {1,  1, -1, -1,  1},
     {1,  1, -1,  1, -1},
     {1,  1,  1, -1, -1},
     {2, -2,  0,  0,  0},
     {2,  2,  2,  0,  0},
     {2,  2,  0,  2,  0},
     {2,  2,  0,  0,  2},
     {2,  2, -2,  0,  0},
     {2,  2,  0, -2,  0},
     {2,  2,  0,  0, -2}};
```

May we know that how to write a function/program such that inputting
such $M$, the program will output the desired $O$.

*For this example the built-in function LatticeReduce works well.
But we are not sure it always works.*

Comment: (1) Would be helpful if your "example" was comprised of cut-and-pastable Mathematica input. (2) What is it about `LatticeReduce` that you are not sure always works? (3) Are you looking for a basis over Q or over Z? If over Q, just use `RowReduce`.

Comment: Also there is `LatticeReduce[DeleteCases[HermiteDecomposition[m][[2]], {0 ..}]]`

Comment: I should say I'm looking for a basis over N. LatticeReduce gives the basis over Z.